# Android studio regex - error while searching over whole project

Tags: regex, android-studio

Why am I getting a stackOverFlowError when running a regex to search a commented string?

```
regex:
/\*(?!\*)(?:.|\W)*?\*/
```

It's not giving an error when I search in a particular Java file, but it does when I search it over the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your regex like this,

```
\/\*(?!\*)[\s\S]*?\*\/
```

`[\S\s]*?` will match any space or non-space charcaters non-greedily. Thus it would match also the line-breaks.

Comment: thanx, it's working, can you please explain why .|\W not working while \s\S is working here.?

Comment: @deepaktiwari it's may be because of escaping the forward slash. Try not escaping the forward slash. And also `(?:.|\W)*` will switch each time when it finds a line break.

Comment: i am not escaping the forward slash, in the expression i'm escaping the * charector, also i think forward slash don't need to be escaped as it's not a special charector. also the .|\W are used with *? so it's non-greedy, but don't know exactly why it's not working.